# Fastlane build failed while releasing to Apple Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, release, fastlane

I use Fastlane to push a build to the App Store. I released the app almost 8 times using this. But this I updated my Xcode10.1 to Xcode11. Somehow I was facing some issue to building. So I rollback to Xcode10.1. Now when I ran my scripts its build successfully but failed with below error.

> Successfully uploaded set of metadata to App Store Connect
>   Successfully uploaded screenshots to App Store Connect Uploading
>   binary to App Store Connect [14:51:03]: Going to upload updated app to
>   App Store Connect [14:51:03]: This might take a few minutes. Please
>   don't interrupt the script.

then after this:

> [Transporter Error Output]: Could not start delivery: all transports
>   failed diagnostics [14:56:09]: Transporter transfer failed.
>   [14:56:09]:  [14:56:09]: Could not start delivery: all transports
>   failed diagnostics [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]  at
>   com.signiant.interactivetransfer.engine.TransferEngine.access$1200(TransferEngine.java:149)
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]     at
>   com.signiant.interactivetransfer.engine.TransferEngine$8.run(TransferEngine.java:4060)
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-09 14:56:09 IST]  DEBUG: Received failed transfer notification; aborting
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-09 14:56:09 IST]   INFO: The Signiant transfer engine's status is DISCONNECTED
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-09 14:56:09 IST]  ERROR:
>   Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter] Package Summary:
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter] 1 package(s) were not uploaded because
>   they had problems:
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]     /tmp/1179206989.itmsp - Error Messages:
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter]         Could not start delivery: all
>   transports failed diagnostics
>
> [14:56:09]: [iTMSTransporter] [2019-10-09 14:56:09 IST]  DBG-X:
>   Returning 1
>
> [14:56:09]: iTunes Transporter output above ^ [14:56:09]: Could not
>   start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics Return status of
>   iTunes Transporter was 1: Could not start delivery: all transports
>   failed diagnostics The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a
>   non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue should be taken to Fastlane's support.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on XCode 11. After some retries of archiving and uploading, it has been working for me as expected till now.

Answer (score 1):

As it was some server related issue. re-ran the scripts for release twice and it worked.

```
iTunes Transporter successfully finished its job
```